# Age Groups stats with PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, function, group-by

I want to display users stats on my website, returning the percentage of age groups like :

```
-13 years : $percent %
13-15 years : $percent %
15-20 years : $percent %
23+ : $percent %
```

In my mysql table i have a column birth_date returning datatime (yyyy-mm-dd).

Did you have hints or idea to do that ?

Comment: [Hints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pure SQL:

```
SELECT
    `group`,
    COUNT(*) as `count`
FROM
`user`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        0 as `start`, 12 as `end`, '0-12' as `group`
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT
        13, 14, '13-14'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        15, 19, '15-19'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        20, 150, '20+'
) `sub`
    ON TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, `birth_date`, NOW()) BETWEEN `start` AND `end`
GROUP BY `group` WITH ROLLUP;
```

Anything else might be calculated via `PHP`.

Comment: I have a NULL array with 3606 entry. I think that this is the numer of users who enter and incorrect or empty date.
But everything is ok, big up to Bichkek ;)

Comment: **@kesm0**, NO, it's a total count of users, matched by `JOIN` condition. Incorrect `birth_date`s are ignored by this query.

Comment: Ok, why did i have groupe = NULL and count = 3606 ?

I have 4073 users

Comment: **@kesm0**, others with invalid dates, that not match join condition. They were ignored. I recommend to fix their birth dates.

Comment: Dont understand, my dates or ok. I got : ex : 1990-12-23 (date)

Comment: **@kesm0**, is this field NULLABLE ?

Comment: my results :
0 - 12 = 32, 13-14 = 350 .... 23 + = 1078 and NULL = 4677. But i just have 4076 account in my table user. Where this NULL value come from ?

Comment: **@kesm0**, remove `WITH ROLLUP`. It calculates last row of the query. Should be Ok then.

Comment: Yes its ok ! Thank you for your help and your time ! I m not a pro in SQL language :/

Answer (score 4):

```
select case when year(curdate() - birth_date) < 13 
            then '< 13 years'
            when year(curdate() - birth_date) between 13 and 14 
            then '13 - 14 years'
            when year(curdate() - birth_date) between 15 and 20 
            then '15 - 20 years'
            when year(curdate() - birth_date) >= 23 
            then '+23 years'
         end as `description`,
       (select count(*) from your_table) / count(*) 
from your_table
group by case when year(curdate() - birth_date) < 13 then 1
              when year(curdate() - birth_date) between 13 and 14 then 2
              when year(curdate() - birth_date) between 15 and 20 then 3
              when year(curdate() - birth_date) >= 23 then 4
         end
```

Comment: Hi ! I dont know how to use it with php.
it return strange array :/

Comment: I would like to use it with a foreach, and display age groups

Comment: If you have a problem in PHP with the query you can ask a new question about it explaining in detail where you are stuck.

Comment: Returning 2 array :
description (NULL, +13years) and  select count(*) from personne) / count(*) (1.4177,3.3942)

Comment: Ok i understand the problem, thank for your help juergen ! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want pure sql:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)    
FROM [table_name]
WHERE birth_date < DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 13 YEAR)


WHERE birth_date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 13 YEAR)
AND birth_date < DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 15 YEAR)

--etc
```

else I would suggest using php to create the dates.

You could union all the queries together and create and sql view eg:

```
CREATE VIEW statistics AS
SELECT "0-13" as age ,COUNT(*) as total
FROM table_name
WHERE birth_date < DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 13 YEAR)
UNION
SELECT "13-15" as age ,COUNT(*) as total
FROM table_name
WHERE birth_date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 13 YEAR)
    AND birth_date < DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 15 YEAR)
UNION
SELECT "15-20" as age ,COUNT(*) as total
FROM table_name
WHERE birth_date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 15 YEAR)
    AND birth_date < DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 20 YEAR)
UNION
SELECT "20-23" as age ,COUNT(*) as total
FROM table_name
WHERE birth_date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 20 YEAR)
    AND birth_date < DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 23 YEAR)
UNION
SELECT "23+" as age ,COUNT(*) as total
FROM table_name
WHERE birth_date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 23 YEAR)
```

Then you can just query:

```
SELECT * from statistics
```

Comment: I like this option, probably the most intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Return datetime as a timestamp, compare with now.offset(years=??), categorize in arrays then count records.